# How to use bdutil and gcloud in python on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I have a python API that interacts with an existing Google Compute Engine cluster via bdutil and gcloud commands.  I am trying to run this API on Google App Engine, and I am having some issues with subprocess and os system executions of bdutil and gcloud commands.  For example,

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["gcloud compute instances list"],
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
out = proc.communicate()
```

returns a list of active GCE instances when run locally, but fails with

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Popen'
```

when run on GAE.

I am aware that 3rd party libraries must be included with the GAE project.  I am also aware that the above command may also be failing to due authentication issues as well.

I am seeking a very detailed, *novice* level, instruction or "hello world" example for how to import, authenticate, and execute bdutil and gcloud commands on a GAE instance, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to run your example from an appengine application as gcloud commands are a command line only utility.

If you want to be able to interact with the compute engine API from an appengine application you will need to incorporate a [3rd party client librar](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/libraries#google_apis_python_client_library)y into your application and call the [appropriate ap](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/compute/v1/python/latest/compute_v1.instances.html)i.